# Permanent fix to Prevent iPhone Voice memos being duplicated on every iTunes Sync

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, voice-memo

This is the only thread that came up: 
[Why is iTunes duplicating my Voice Memos?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8758/why-is-itunes-duplicating-my-voice-memos)

- It's out of date and does not provide a solution, hack or workaround if one exists
- Neither does it say that this is a current bug that cannot be solved

I'd like a solution, hack or workaround if someone has figured some way out to "Prevent" this long term.