# Locating the iBooks folder in iCloud Drive (on Windows)

Tags: terminal, icloud, windows, books

I need to get the iBooks that are saved in iCloud Drive, using Windows, in a folder path and / or command line solution.

This is a spin-off from [Locating the iBooks folder in iCloud Drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296462/locating-the-ibooks-folder-in-icloud-drive?newreg=1d6ae7995129403b99e57fe74feae430) which only has answers for Apple macOS command line (macOS bash), while I need this for Windows.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150935/discussion-on-question-by-questionto42-locating-the-ibooks-folder-in-icloud-driv); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Summing up the answer in advance: the folder simply might not exist on Windows.*

And the workaround in advance:

**If you cannot locate the folder, the only solution is via extraction from the iTunes backup (and there is also another new answer with the help of an iPad), see:**
[iPhone: bulk move ALL voice memos + ALL pdfs generated from Safari page prints (pdf-exports using "Books") to pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62434692/iphone-move-in-one-go-all-pdfs-generated-from-safari-page-prints-which-i-fr/62701384#62701384).

There was also once the same question here on Ask Different, but [it can only be seen by moderators since I asked to delete it long time ago](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/395277/381223). **I shall revive that old deleted Ask Different question here and ask you to vote to undelete it.** I am not sure whether I can revive a question here while the other question is closed since that would make a cross-site duplicate.

I do not like to delete the one on Stack Overflow since it has a better answer. A long time ago, I did not want to delete the one on Stack Overflow since I had spent a bounty on it which gave me a badge and since it had more upvotes and views, and I urgently needed an answer. I was new and did not know about cross-site duplicates, I thought I would just get a faster answer if I post it both here and there.*

---

I found a description that explains the equivalent Windows and Mac folders at [How to Back Up iBooks PDFs](https://deciphertools.com/blog/how-to-backup-ibooks-pdfs/).

> Where are My iBooks PDFs Stored on my Computer?
>
> **On Windows**, the iBooks PDF files copied to your iTunes by doing Transfer Purchases are stored in your computer user's account folder, alongside your iTunes music. Here's how to find your iBooks PDFs on your Windows computer: **Go into your user account's Music folder. (On Windows 10, this would show up under This PC -> Music.) Open the folders iTunes -> iTunes Media -> Books.** You should see your PDFs in this folder.
>
> **On Mac**, the iBooks PDFs copied by doing Transfer Purchases are tucked away in data for the iBooks Mac App. Here's how to find your iBooks PDFs on your Mac: Open Finder, and select the "Go" menu at the top of the screen. **Hold the Option key (or Shift + Option on latest Sierra builds), and select the "Library" menu option from the Go menu. (On OSX Lion and above, Library will only appear with the Option key held.) From Library, navigate to Containers -> com.apple.BKAgentService -> Data -> Documents -> iBooks -> Books.** You should see your PDFs in this folder.

Then there comes an explanation of how to use iBooks for iCloud, but only on Mac:

> First, we need to make sure you've got iBooks turned on for your iCloud drive documents on your Mac.
>
> - From the Apple menu at the top of the screen, select System Preferences.
> - Select iCloud in System Preferences.
> - Next to iCloud Drive, press the "Options..." button.
> - Ensure the iBooks checkbox is checked.

The checkbox "iBooks" does not exist in my **iCloud** > **iCloud Drive** settings. This could mean that it is simply not possible to sync iBooks with iCloud on Windows, as @MatthewBarclay commented above. This is also plausible, because my iBooks are backed up, and Apple does only one thing of the both, either sync or backup. And then, to answer the question, there simply is no such folder.

I have also tried opening it in Terminal, as it could be hidden as the answer stated at [Locating the iBooks folder in iCloud Drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/296462/locating-the-ibooks-folder-in-icloud-drive?newreg=1d6ae7995129403b99e57fe74feae430), and I could not find it:

`C:\Users\USER\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media>dir /a`

does not have it, showing both hidden and unhidden items with `/a` (for `/a` see [How to see hidden files in MS-DOS and the Command Prompt](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001039.htm)).

Perhaps my sync settings are corrupt or wrong because I marked iBooks to be included in iCloud, but they are in my iTunes backup instead (proven), and they can only be in the backup OR in the iCloud (not in both, thus, they seem to be **only** in the backup) if I am not mistaken. **Settings** > **Books** > **iCloud Drive** is switched on, that cannot be the issue, following [How to Sync iBooks to All your iOS Devices](https://www.topmobiletech.com/how-to-sync-ibooks-to-all-your-ios-devices/).
I will not test this anymore, please test yourself and set a different answer which I will accept in case you find more.

Comment: "*C:\Users\USER\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media>cd iBooks

or

C:\Users\USER\Music\iTunes\iTunes Media>cd books*" It's case sensitive. And it's named `Books` on Mac. You should use something command to list all subfolders there, even the hidden ones.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed to dir /a now to show hidden and unhidden files/folders. I really think that Apple simply does not provide this on Windows, they will have their reasons, such disadvantages on Windows keep iPhone users linked to iMacs.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the iBooks PDF files copied to your iTunes by doing Transfer Purchases are stored in your computer user's account folder, alongside your iTunes music.

Here's how to find your iBooks PDFs on your Windows computer: Go into your user account's Music folder. (On Windows 10, this would show up under **This PC** > **Music**.) Open the folders **iTunes** > **iTunes Media** > **Books**. You should see your PDFs in this folder.

Comment: Hi and thanks, this is a misunderstanding: the question is about the (i)Books folder in iCloud Drive. The iTunes Media\Books folder on Windows only has the "Transfer Purchases" pdfs, but not the rest of the pdfs you may have for example from Safari printouts or whatever. Your answer is therefore already part of the other answer. This gets lost a bit in the long answer. :) The only way to get the non-"Transfer Purchases" pdfs is by getting the pdfs from the backup.